# При объявлении переменной в функции она не видна при импорте в другой файл

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

У меня есть файл main где объявляется переменная phonenumber
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее она импортируется в другой файл from index.telegram.main import phonenumber и используется

В данной функции ей присваиваются значения в файле main
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но т.к переменная объявляется в самом начале, то у неё всегда значение no, а если её объявить в какой-то функции, то при импорте возникает ошибка cannot import name 'phonenumber' from 'index.telegram.main' (/mnt/c/WEB/codepython/PaymentForParking/index/telegram/main.py). Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял в чём проблема. Вы хотите объявлять переменную внутри функции и потом использовать (например импортировать) снаружи функции? Если объявить эту переменную как `global phonenumber` это не поможет?

Comment: У меня есть файл main где я в функции объявляю переменную. Далее в другом файле я импортирую данную переменную from index.telegram.main import phonenumber и получаю ошибку невозможно импортировать имя 'номер телефона' из 'index.telegram.main' (/mnt/c/WEB/codepython/PaymentForParking/index/telegram/main.py). Применение global не помогает. Если объявлять переменную вне функции, то она всегда имеет значение no т.к она объявляется как phonenumber = "no"

Comment: добавляйте код как текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть нужно, как-то вычислять значение переменной до её импорта?

Это можно делать так:

```
def get_value():
    value = 'no'
    return value

phonenum = get_value()
```

И дальше импортируем переменную и используем как обычно:

```
from global_var import phonenum

print(phonenum) # 'no'
```

---

**Update**

Сделал файл `main.py` и в нём определил `phonenumber` таким образом

```
# @bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])

def contact(message):
    if message is not None:
        keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно отправили свой номер', reply_markup=keyboard2)
        phonenumber = message.contact.phone_number
        # print(phonenumber)
    else:
        phonenumber = "Hi there"
    return phonenumber

phonenumber = contact(None)
```

Сделал другой файл и в нёго импортировал `phonenumber` и распечатал:

```
from main import phonenumber

print(phonenumber) # it prints "Hi there"
```

Всё работает. В чём подвох?

Comment: Если я её объявляю в функции, то при импорте возникает ошибка cannot import name 'phonenumber' from 'index.telegram.main. Если её объявлять за пределами функции, то всё  работает. Но мне надо определять её в функции

Comment: Код:(/mnt/c/WEB/codepython/PaymentForParking/index/telegram/main.py). Код функции: @bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно отправили свой номер', reply_markup=keyboard2)
        phonenumber = message.contact.phone_number
        print(phonenumber)
        return phonenumber

Comment: Обновил ответ. Всё равно не понимаю, в чём проблема.